# AUGraphConnectNodeInput returns OSStatus -10861

Tags: ios, core-audio, audiounit

I have a Audio Unit graph which looks like that:

```
mixer0 -> lowpass -> mixer1 -> output
```

The connection is done using commands like this:

```
error = AUGraphConnectNodeInput(audioUnitGraph,
                                lowpass,0,
                                mixer1,0);
```

Everything is working so far. But once a rendering callback is set to the mixer1 node using `AUGraphSetNodeInputCallback`  `AUGraphConnectNodeInput` returns `OSStatus -10861`.

What is wrong?